# angular-ui/bootstrap Modal window

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to work on a sample application to display angular-ui bootstrap modal window.

Below is the javascript code

```
'use strict';
var TicketApp = angular.module('TicketApp', ['ngNotify', 'ui.bootstrap']);

var CreateCtrl = TicketApp.controller('CreateCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, ngNotify, $modal) {


$scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,          
        template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">title modal!</h3></div><div class="modal-body">Model Body Comes here !!</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size
    })

};

$scope.CreateTicket = function () {
                                     $scope.open();
                                  }
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = TicketApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function   ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

});
```

When $scope.open() gets called , "Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items <- ModalInstanceCtrl" gets displayed in chrome console.

Please let me know why this error is getting displayed.

Comment: The error is saying that the `ModalInstanceCtrl` wants `items` to be injected into it. But the code you've shown isn't injecting anything called `items`. The UI Bootstrap modal has a `resolve` property that you can use (for example, to pass an array of items to the dialog). Are you using the resolve? Is there any more code involved?

Comment: @Sunil D , As you mentioned , resolve property was missing.After adding the resolve property , error got fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes my original code also had "$scope.items = items;"  in ModalInstanceCtrl control.